# Check if split() in php worked

Tags: php, list, split

```
list($time, $content) = split("-", $item, 2);  
list($hours, $mins) = split(":", $time, 2);
```

How can I determine if the 1st split() [line 1] works before proceeding to [line2]?

Comment: Don't use `split`! It's deprecated and way slower that its PCRE equivalent `preg_split`. From what I can see, `explode` might also do the trick for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($time && $content) {
  list($hours, $mins) = split(":", $time, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in getting the date parts, you should really use a function like `date_parse()` or `strtotime()`/`date()` to extract the parts. Check it out - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php

This will also perform some validation whereas your custom code does not.